# Oracle SQL PHP INSERT speed optimization?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to insert a lot of data into a Oracle SQL DB, doing the following...

```
foreach ($service as $valor) {
    $j=0;
    foreach($fechahorainf as $fecha){
        $i=0;
        $consulta="INSERT INTO PRUEBA_SMS(FECHAHORAINF,SERVICIO,VALOR) VALUES (TO_DATE('".$fecha."','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss'),'".$valor."','".$data[$j][$i]."')";
        $stmt = oci_parse($conexion, $consulta);
        oci_execute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT);
        $i++;
    }
    oci_commit($conexion);
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    $j++;
}
```

Note that `count($j)=count($service)=30` and `count($i)=count($fechahorainf)=720`

The point here is that I'm going to INSERT 21600 rows and it takes a lot of time.

Is there some tip to improve the speed?

Update: I tried the LOAD DATE INFILE that Daan and citywall sugested by this way:

```
$consulta="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'files/data.csv' INTO TABLE PRUEBA_SMS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (FECHAHORAINF,NODO,SERVICIO,VALOR)";
$stmt=oci_parse($conexion, $consulta);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

but I receive this Warning without much information...
`Warning: oci_execute(): in C:\PATH_TO_ARCHIVE.php on line 160`

Regards!

Comment: Create a .txt file and put your insert statements in there then do `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: Does the command `LOAD DATA INFILE` work on a Oracle DB? Because I'm reading that it's MySQL...

Comment: Yes oracle's syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/load-data.html

Comment: So, I only need to change the `$consulta` variable to point to my full local text file? I'll try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case LOAD DATA for some reason is not an option for you, this is the steps I would recommend taking to improve speed:

1) Make sure there is no auto-commit going on. You are committing yes, but if there is no transaction without auto-commit going on, it just will not matter.
Since you are using OCI_DEFAULT there should be no auto-commit.

2) Do not parse the SQL for every insert ... reuse the parsed SQL and replace the values to insert using OCI_bind_by_name .. see the second [sample](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php) on how to do this.
This should speed up the insert a lot ... and optimize network traffic, SQL parsing resources at the DB and so on.

3) Instead of committing for every group, count the inserts and try out for the optimal commit rate - but this last point is not something that I think will matter a lot in this case.

I would try out step 2 and see how much you can gain from avoiding to parse the SQL for every insert ...